# Pygame - pygame.init() not working on my Ubuntu system

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

Recently I have switched over to an Ubuntu system, and I am trying to get Pygame to run. I have installed the module and I can import it perfectly well. However, when I try to use the function `pygame.init()` I get the following error.

`ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave`

I was wondering if anyone else has had this error and how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be an audio driver problem, check if [this](https://dev.to/setevoy/linux-alsa-lib-pcmdmixc1108sndpcmdmixopen-unable-to-open-slave-38on) helps out.

Comment: Could you copy the important parts over to this answer? If there's a license prohibiting you, then write so. Link-only answers have limited usability, especially if the link one day dies.